# MS SQL - Average Rows with specific columns

Tags: t-sql

Hey everyone I am looking to figure out how to Create an Average over time with the following select from a table.

```
MinutesToLoad |Environment | Server | Exchange | StartTime |EndTime

140 ENVIRONMENT_A | Server2 | TAI | 2013-01-06 17:22:44.000 | 2013-01-06 19:42:53.000
135 ENVIRONMENT_A | Server2 | TAI | 2013-01-07 17:23:21.000 | 2013-01-07 19:38:37.000
130 ENVIRONMENT_A | Server2 | TAI | 2013-01-08 17:24:03.000 | 2013-01-08 19:34:17.000
130 ENVIRONMENT_A | Server2 | TAI | 2013-01-09 17:24:42.000 | 2013-01-09 19:34:45.000
140 ENVIRONMENT_A | Server1 | TAI | 2013-01-06 17:22:44.000 | 2013-01-06 19:42:53.000
135 ENVIRONMENT_A | Server1 | TAI | 2013-01-07 17:23:21.000 | 2013-01-07 19:38:37.000
130 ENVIRONMENT_A | Server1 | TAI | 2013-01-08 17:24:03.000 | 2013-01-08 19:34:17.000
130 ENVIRONMENT_A | Server1 | TAI | 2013-01-09 17:24:42.000 | 2013-01-09 19:34:45.000
1430    ENVIRONMENT_A | Server1 | SET | 2013-01-07 00:03:01.000 | 2013-01-07 23:53:37.000
1431    ENVIRONMENT_A | Server1 | SET | 2013-01-08 00:03:36.000 | 2013-01-08 23:54:14.000
1430    ENVIRONMENT_A | Server1 | SET | 2013-01-09 00:04:14.000 | 2013-01-09 23:54:55.000
1430    ENVIRONMENT_A | Server2 | SET | 2013-01-07 00:03:01.000 | 2013-01-07 23:53:37.000
1431    ENVIRONMENT_A | Server2 | SET | 2013-01-08 00:03:36.000 | 2013-01-08 23:54:14.000
1430    ENVIRONMENT_A | Server2 | SET | 2013-01-09 00:04:14.000 | 2013-01-09 23:54:55.000
1   ENVIRONMENT_A | Server2 | QXI | 2013-01-08 03:23:57.000 | 2013-01-08 03:24:02.000
1   ENVIRONMENT_A | Server1 | QXI | 2013-01-08 03:23:57.000 | 2013-01-08 03:24:02.000
```

MinutesToLoad is really a DATEDIFF(MINUTE,startTime,EndTime) on my select procedure, but the rest are from a table.

The goal result would be to have this result look like this:

```
MinutesToLoadOverLast10Days - Environment - Server - Exchange 
133                          ENVIRONMENT_A   Server2 TAI 
133                          ENVIRONMENT_A   Server1 TAI 
1430                         ENVIRONMENT_A   Server1 SET
1430                         ENVIRONMENT_A   Server2 SET
1                            ENVIRONMENT_A   Server2 QXI
1                            ENVIRONMENT_A   Server1 QXI
```

I know I will be using the AVG function but I am lost on trying to figure out to use it to get the result I want.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to `AVG()`?

Comment: Averaging the Minutes To Load over the last X days using StartTime as the reference (start and EndTime will always be on the same day)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select avg(MinutesToLoadOverLast10Days),Environment, Server,Exchange 
FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY Environment, Server,Exchange
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess i was over thinking it !